# Connection Between SharePoint Online Project Site and Project Pro 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, ms-project

My organization runs SharePoint Online for internal use. We have a project site setup using the default template with no customization beyond the default template. One of our departments wanted more functionality so they ordered Project Pro 2013 licenses. When they click Open with Project on the project site list ribbon they receive the following error message:

> We are unable to connect right now. Please check your network and try again later.

I am unfamiliar with MS Project Pro 2013.

Do we require Project Online with Project Pro 2013 to connect to a SharePoint Online project site?

I read an article saying to enable two site collection features: 
Project Web App Ribbon
Project Web App Settings

Project Web App Ribbon activates normally but Project Web App Settings gives me the error:

> An unexpected error has occurred.

I am provided a correlation ID to take to Microsoft for assistance. Before doing this I want to make sure that I have the correct software to make this connection in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow the question been sitting here since February with 87 views and no comment at least? Anyways I am on the same dilemma as you, but I think it is because you will need to purchase Project Online license. I'm thinking maybe you already figured it out by this time. At least maybe other users looking for answers might lead them in the right direction. There is this article I found too. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/projectsupport/2013/05/15/project-online-getting-to-project-web-app/

Comment: Purchasing project online licenses did solve the problem. Thank you for providing this solution. I had forgotten to provide the answer myself.